# Configure Azure DevOps Server to send email using Office365

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to configure my Azure DevOps Server to send emails using my Office 365 account, with no luck.
I tried setting the SMTP server as indicated on this page: [POP, IMAP, and SMTP settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353) but it doesn't work and gives me an error if I try to send an email ("Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail").

Is there a way to configure it properly?
Or as an alternative, do you know of any SMTP server/proxy that I can install to work around the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you need to check the "This server requires a secured connection (SSL)" checkbox and **restart the server**.